Ubuntu 24.04 LTS - Buttons of maximized window does not work (minimize, maximize and close)
I have the following issue. I upgraded from 22.04 LTS to 23.04 LTS and finally to 24.04 LTS.
Main monitor (monitor 1)
After the upgrades the installation is ok. When I maximize a window the buttons do not work any more (red area), when I press any of the read area clicks. In this case AnyDesk. if I move the maximized window I have the same behavior. Working with minimized window works ok.
Second Monitor (monitor 2)
Does not have this issue. The issue is that the second monitor screen blinks all the time.
enter image description here
Regarding the issue tried the following.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2486259 > With this command I go bach to the bar menu of Ubuntu 23.04.
Settings window does not open in Ubuntu 22.04 > Update the bar menu to 24.04 but the issue persist.

I'll try a clean installation this weekend and go back with comments.

I don't see a question here.

A new installation was needed. Anydesk generated some issues with the top icon, blocking the options of the top right corner.
More problems with overheat during a normal use of Ubuntu 24.04. This happen with Dell Latitud 5290.

Problem is caused by Anydesk icon on top bar. If you disable anydesk.service, the problem is gone. To do that you can use:
sudo systemctl disable anydesk.service

When you open Anydesk, problem will come back, I hope they will solve this soon.

Just simply go to /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
if file is there just simply rename it with appIndicator.bak.
sudo mv appIndicator.js appIndicator.bak

and just restart your system.
